# C# - Estrutura de Repetição em Cascata

Tags: c#, array, foreach, while

primeiramente bom dia!

Tenho uma tarefa de alimentar uma "árvore de arquivos (estilo windows explorer)" em formato de objeto.

Para isso eu tenho inicialmente um método que lista todos os arquivos e pastas do diretório `root` do sistema de arquivos, e com base da tipagem destes (que pode variar entre `Pasta` e `Arquivo`) eu devo alimentar a propriedade com o conteúdo dessa pasta.

Meu problema é que eu só consigo alimentar a primeira camada deste objeto, deixando suas sub-pastas ainda vazias. Ou seja, minha chamada `while` não desce para os demais níveis.
Alguém consegue dizer o que eu errei?

```
    public async Task<List<Arquivo>> ListarArquivosEPastas()
    {
        try
        {
            var arquivos = await ListarArquivosOuPastas("/");

            foreach (var arquivo in arquivos)
            {
                while (arquivo.Tipo == "Pasta" && arquivo.Conteudo is null)
                {
                    arquivo.Conteudo = await ListarArquivosOuPastasPorIdDiretorio(arquivo.Id);
                }
            }

            return arquivos;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Ilustração de como o retorno está vindo: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: sem ver o código dos outros métodos e tbm saber o que retornar na variável arquivos fica bem difícil ajudar

Comment: @RicardoPontual Eles retornam basicamente um novo array com os arquivos e pastas daquele diretório. Editei o post com uma imagem em anexo de como este retorno é em detalhes

Comment: olha nessa essa estrutra em árvore o segredo vai estar no método `ListarArquivosOuPastasPorIdDiretorio`, que deve ter uma chamada recursiva, e também a classe que vai ter esses dados precisar se uma um tipo de lista encadeada, senão não vai conseguir sair do primeiro nível. Precisa ser algo como `Class Arvore { Pasta Pasta {get; set; } ` e `Class Pasta { Pasta PastaPai { get; set; } List<Arquivo> Arquivos { get; set; } }`

Comment: se tiver dúvidas avisa, ai posto uma resposta